# determine maximum value of each row with the column name in Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby, data-cleaning

I have a table which's been attached.
The table includes a different number of model of cars with their EU class (columns are a number of models in each class).
I am trying to identify the maximum value of each model (at each row) by identifying the EU class (column name) in Python.
for example the first row the maximum number goes to Euro 5 with 3677 cars whose model of vehicle is 320 GH.
I tried different commands such as

```
maxValuesObj = D_high_model_EUstd.loc[D_high_model_EUstd['Model of Vehicle'].idxmax()]
```

but faced this error  "reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this type".
I was wondering if anybody can help or suggest to me any solution.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pd.idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

For example:

```
df.drop(columns="Model of Vehicle").idxmax(axis=1) # Drop text column since idxmax don't work with them
```

Or create another dataframe:

```
pd.concat({
    "Model of Vehicle": df["Model of Vehicle"],
    "Max":df.drop(columns="Model of Vehicle").idxmax(axis=1)
},axis=1)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Can you marked it as a accepted answer? Thanks @Allin

Comment: Hasan, I marked your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Can I ask another question related to multiplying values in excel file multiple sheets using Pandas?

Comment: It sound like you need to ask that in another question. I think it is not related to this question. But if you ask here i can try to answer it.

Comment: Thanks Hassan  for getting back to me